# I want to display text in column header of ssrs 2019 like below image

Tags: reporting-services

I want to display text in column header of ssrs 2019[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk9Zs.png) like below image

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom code

```
Public Function ToVertical( s As String) As String

Dim a() As String = Split(s)
Dim maxchars As Integer
Dim sb as new System.Text.StringBuilder()

For Each item As String In a
    If Len(item)> maxchars Then maxchars = Len(item)
Next


For i As Integer = 0 To maxchars - 1
For Each item As String In a
  If i<Len(item) Then 
  sb.append( item(i) )
  Else 
  sb.append( " " )
End If  
Next
sb.AppendLine()
Next
 
Return sb.toString()

End Function
```

For your expression use `= Code.ToVertical(Fields!FieldName.Value)`

[image]

Comment: nice approach! although monospaced fonts should be used to format the results :)

Comment: Thanks! You are right about monospaced fonts! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in feature called the `WritingMode` property to orient the text vertically. This rotates it by either 90 or 270 degrees. Hopefully that is a viable alternative for you.

In order to get exactly what you pictured, you'd have to write some custom code to put the first letter of each word on the first line etc. And potentially build word-wrapping into it. But it's not a built-in feature.